# Debugging a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, polymorphism

I'm getting a `NullPointException` Error in this class for a reason I cannot figure out. This class SHOULD successfully create a list of employers, a list of employees to be stored inside that, and then display all the employers and their employees. At the moment, it seems that the for loops below are somehow adding up to `NullPointException` errors.

Here is the full code for my TEST class, the line above is further on down.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestEmployer {

    public static void main(String agrs[]) {

        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, esize = 0;

        System.out.println("Number of employers: ");
        int size = get.nextInt();

        while (size < 5) {
            System.out.println("Size must be at least 5: ");
            size = get.nextInt();
        }

        Employer list[] = new Employer[size];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("How many employees? ");
            esize = get.nextInt();

            while (esize < 10) {
                System.out.println("Must be at least size 10: ");
                esize = get.nextInt();
            }

            Employee elist[] = new Employee[esize];
            for (j = 0; j < esize; j++) {
                elist[i] = randomEmployee();
            }
            list[i] = new Employer(randomEmployer(), elist, "507", 1000.00);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s: ", list[i].getName());
            for (j = 0; j < esize; j++) {
                System.out.printf("\n%s", list[i].getEmployees()[j].toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any clues as to where this null pointer exception error is coming from?

I apologize for not showing the original error message. Here it is:

```
Lucas 07/03/1973 06/06/1965:(salaried) 19929.33Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestEmployer.main(TestEmployer.java:53)
```

As you can see above, it prints the first employee along with his information, and then dies.

*edit 2: I apologize for the code before, this is the updated code (without the confusing variable names)

Comment: `j < list2` this conditional makes no sense, does that even compile?

Comment: I would add: please be nice and choose good variable names

Comment: You also seem to have at least two different `list2` variables, one an int variable, the other an Employee array -- very confusing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh that explains it

Comment: Thank you. Which line is line 53? `TestEmployer.java:53`

Comment: I apologize everyone, I rushed through creating this question when I should not have.

Comment: `System.out.printf("\n%s",list[i].getEmployees()[j].toString());` is line 53, it's near the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from your `esize` int variable holding the length of the last array stored in your first list (you continue to overwrite the same variable with the lengths of each array), therefore you can easily overstep the bounds of the array when looping and displaying.

```
for(j=0; j < esize; j++){
```

should probably be

```
for(j=0; j < list[i].getEmployees().length; j++){
```

Comment: This is a very good point, however the same problem persists.

Comment: Are you certain you are setting your employees array correctly within your employer object?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
           System.out.printf("\n%s",list[i].getEmployees()[j].toString());
```

A `NullPointerException` means that you're trying to dereference something that's actually `null`. That means that one of these is true:

1. `System.out` is `null` (nope!)
2. `list` is `null` (unlikely with your code)
3. `list` has a `null` element in it (probably not; you appear to treat it correctly)
4. `getEmployees()` is returning a `null` instead of an array.
5. The array returned by `getEmployees()` has a `null` in it somewhere.

I'd really check points 4 and 5 carefully.

---

Your printing code would be better done as:

```
for (Employer employer: list) {
    System.out.printf("%s: ", employer.getName());
    for (Employee employee: employer.getEmployees()) {
        System.out.printf("\n%s", employee);
    }
}
```

The `%s` causes the `toString()` method to be used, and using collection-iteration is much easier to get right. It also deals with the major bug in your code (though not the one that's hitting you here) where different employers have varying numbers of employees; a single `esize` variable won't cut it, but “fortunately” (i.e., *deliberately,* in the language design!) arrays know their own length.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but it does look a lot like it is the second element that is `null`. Not putting so many dereferences on one line (see the suggested alternative printing code) will make the error message more informative.